# Open Rss Reader Activity from Fragment using Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, rss

Ive been working on a project that I want to get done before the world cup begins. 
Ive been using the SlidingMenu from AndroidHive and also an RssReader. Also I am new to android programming, and having alot of trouble using Fragments.

Basically, I want to display Soccer Group Data using TextViews and Imageviews from each fragment. The  problem Ive been having is applying a Button that actually opens the Activity without crashing. This question has been asked before in this thread:

[How to start Activity from Fragment? Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22467759/how-to-start-activity-from-fragment-android)

Ive been trying to implement asynctask, but I just cant get it to work. 
The Code is 100% the same as described in the link i posted.

Here is a Zip of both files, can somebody help me out? 
http://www.file-upload.net/download-8963794/SlidingMenu.zip.html

Thanks in advance to anybody who can help me out!

Comment: I'll check on the code and get back to you.

Comment: You gotta use AsyncTask to execute the method on your onCreate. It's giving networkonMainThread exception.

Comment: Your code is working now. I am posting it as an answer. Go through it and lemme know when it works for you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Just do the following to make your code working:**

Just copy and paste as below. Nothing much to do other than that. Lemme know if you need more explanation to the code.

**NOTE:** To start an Activity from fragment, you need to use getActivity() and then the intent like this,

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        AndroidRssReader.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
```

**1) Just change your code a bit in your FindPeopleFragment:**

```
public class FindPeopleFragment extends Fragment {

    public FindPeopleFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_find_people,
                container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        Button newPage = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        newPage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),
                        AndroidRssReader.class);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**2) Modify your AndroidRssReader to this:**

```
public class AndroidRssReader extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> item = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static final String MAIN_URL = "http://drinkandtink.bugs3.com/covendos/Android-er%3Fformat%3Dxml";

    Context context;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        context = this;

        new BackgroundTask(context, MAIN_URL).execute();

    }

    public void getImpData(String URL) {

        try {
            URL rssUrl = new URL(URL);
            SAXParserFactory mySAXParserFactory = SAXParserFactory
                    .newInstance();
            SAXParser mySAXParser = mySAXParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader myXMLReader = mySAXParser.getXMLReader();
            RSSHandler myRSSHandler = new RSSHandler();
            myXMLReader.setContentHandler(myRSSHandler);
            InputSource myInputSource = new InputSource(rssUrl.openStream());
            myXMLReader.parse(myInputSource);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        Context mcontext;
        String someURL;
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        public BackgroundTask(Context context, String SomeURL) {

            super();
            this.mcontext = context;
            this.someURL = SomeURL;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
            pDialog.setMessage("Checking Network Connection");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMax(100);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            getImpData(someURL);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            ArrayAdapter<String> itemList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    R.layout.rsslist, item);
            setListAdapter(itemList);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }

    }

    private class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {
        final int stateUnknown = 0;
        final int stateTitle = 1;
        int state = stateUnknown;

        @Override
        public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void endDocument() throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                state = stateTitle;
            } else {
                state = stateUnknown;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
                throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            state = stateUnknown;
        }

        @Override
        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String strCharacters = new String(ch, start, length);
            if (state == stateTitle) {
                item.add(strCharacters);

            }
        }

    }

}
```

It's working perfect now..make sure to accept my answer for future viewers.. Enjoyy .. :D

Comment: You can do other formatting and stuff. But for now, your code is working perfectly fine and if you do need explanation to this code, let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much!You are a god among men. If you watch the world cup, i would be happy to send you a complete copy of the application once its working.

Comment: That's perfect.. I'll try your app..:D..if there's any questions regarding the code above, please do ask questions and also, if you have questions in the future, do ask me for that. If I am able to answer, i will definitely try to answer that. Good Luck..:)